# Анимация кругового прелоадера

Tags: css, canvas, анимация, svg, css-animation

Я пытаюсь создать анимацию Apple's OS X  загрузчика.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То, что я уже попробовал:

```css
.animation-wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  filter: brightness(0.8);
  -webkit-filter: brightness(0.8);
}
.pie-piece1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 0, 1) 100%);
}
.pie-piece2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 255, 0, 1) 100%);
}
.pie-piece3 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 0, 255, 1) 100%);
}
.pie-piece4 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 0, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 255, 1) 100%);
}
.rotating-spinners {
  position: absolute;
}
.spike {
  fill: rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<figure class="animation-wrapper">
  <div class="pie-piece1"></div>
  <div class="pie-piece2"></div>
  <div class="pie-piece3"></div>
  <div class="pie-piece4"></div>
  <svg class="rotating-spinners" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
      <path id="spin-part" class="spike" d="M 65,-40 C 65,-40 80,20 50,50 60,40 50,-40 50,-40Z" />
    </defs>
    <use x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#spin-part" />
    <use x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#spin-part" transform="rotate(60, 50, 50)" />
    <use x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#spin-part" transform="rotate(120, 50, 50)" />
    <use x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#spin-part" transform="rotate(180, 50, 50)" />
    <use x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#spin-part" transform="rotate(240, 50, 50)" />
    <use x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#spin-part" transform="rotate(300, 50, 50)" />
  </svg>
</figure>
```

Линейные градиенты неправильно направлены.  Я не смог найти способ сделать градиент, идущий в двух направлениях.
Есть ли способ, чтобы создать это, используя только CSS или SVG, не смешивая их, как это сделал я?

Или есть другие решения, может использовать `canvas`, или какую-то другую магию?

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Circle loading animation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31247310/7394871) от участника  [@Persijn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3999748/persijn).</sub>

Comment: Уверен, что это можно сделать при помощи `conic-gradient` http://leaverou.github.io/conic-gradient/

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31247310/circle-loading-animation/31250477#31250477

Comment: Добавлены два ответа

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вот моя SVG-только версия.  Цвет фона колеса не идеален, но я думаю, что  получилось довольно близко.

```html
<svg width="135" height="135" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
    <defs>
        <filter id="blur" color-interpolation-filters="linear">
            <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="11"/>
        </filter>
        <mask id="mask">
            <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="90" fill="white"/>
        </mask>
        <linearGradient id="gloss" x2="0" y2="0.4">
            <stop offset="0" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0.5"/>
            <stop offset="1" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0"/>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>

    <g transform="translate(100,100)" mask="url(#mask)">
        <g filter="url(#blur)">
            <polygon points="0,0, -100,-26.8, -100,26.8" fill="#c44"/>
            <polygon points="0,0, -100,-26.8, -100,26.8" fill="#c09" transform="rotate(30)"/>
            <polygon points="0,0, -100,-26.8, -100,26.8" fill="#c0c" transform="rotate(60)"/>
            <polygon points="0,0, -100,-26.8, -100,26.8" fill="#90c" transform="rotate(90)"/>
            <polygon points="0,0, -100,-26.8, -100,26.8" fill="#44c" transform="rotate(120)"/>
            <polygon points="0,0, -100,-26.8, -100,26.8" fill="#09c" transform="rotate(150)"/>
            <polygon points="0,0, -100,-26.8, -100,26.8" fill="#0cc" transform="rotate(180)"/>
            <polygon points="0,0, -100,-26.8, -100,26.8" fill="#0c9" transform="rotate(210)"/>
            <polygon points="0,0, -100,-26.8, -100,26.8" fill="#4c4" transform="rotate(240)"/>
            <polygon points="0,0, -100,-26.8, -100,26.8" fill="#9c0" transform="rotate(270)"/>
            <polygon points="0,0, -100,-26.8, -100,26.8" fill="#cc0" transform="rotate(300)"/>
            <polygon points="0,0, -100,-26.8, -100,26.8" fill="#c90" transform="rotate(330)"/>
        </g>
        <g transform="scale(0.9,0.9)">
            <path d="M0,0C5,-61,-32,-86,-95,-90L-100,-46C-65,-53,-24,-35,0,0Z" fill="black" fill-opacity="0.4"/>
            <path d="M0,0C5,-61,-32,-86,-95,-90L-100,-46C-65,-53,-24,-35,0,0Z" fill="black" fill-opacity="0.4" transform="rotate(60)"/>
            <path d="M0,0C5,-61,-32,-86,-95,-90L-100,-46C-65,-53,-24,-35,0,0Z" fill="black" fill-opacity="0.4" transform="rotate(120)"/>
            <path d="M0,0C5,-61,-32,-86,-95,-90L-100,-46C-65,-53,-24,-35,0,0Z" fill="black" fill-opacity="0.4" transform="rotate(180)"/>
            <path d="M0,0C5,-61,-32,-86,-95,-90L-100,-46C-65,-53,-24,-35,0,0Z" fill="black" fill-opacity="0.4" transform="rotate(240)"/>
            <path d="M0,0C5,-61,-32,-86,-95,-90L-100,-46C-65,-53,-24,-35,0,0Z" fill="black" fill-opacity="0.4" transform="rotate(300)"/>
            <animateTransform attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0" to="360" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>

        </g>
        <circle r="83" fill="url(#gloss)"/>
        <circle r="90" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [Circle loading animation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292848/paul-lebeau) от участника  [@Paul LeBeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292848/paul-lebeau).</sub>

Answer (score 2):

В моем варианте ответа конический градиент - это встроенное растровое изображение, извлеченное путем вычисления максимального значения каждого пикселя в анимированном GIF,  приведённым автором вопроса.

Полупрозрачный черный `pattern` крыльев ветряной мельницы накладывается поверх него и анимируется, а фильтр размытия избавляет от артефактов JPEG.

(Edit: добавлена отражающая подсветка, чтобы она выглядела немного более трехмерной)

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  width="121" height="121" viewBox="0 0 121 121">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="circ">
      <circle r="60" cx="60.5" cy="60.5"/>
    </clipPath>
    <linearGradient id="shine" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:#fff;stop-opacity:0.6" />
      <stop offset="10%" style="stop-color:#fff;stop-opacity:0.3" />
      <stop offset="20%" style="stop-color:#fff;stop-opacity:0.1" />
      <stop offset="40%" style="stop-color:#fff;stop-opacity:0" />
    </linearGradient>
    <filter id="blur">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="2"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <image width="121" height="121" filter="url(#blur)" xlink:href="data:image/jpeg;base64,
  /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/2wBDACAWGBwYFCAcGhwkIiAmMFA0MCwsMGJGSjpQdGZ6eHJm
  cG6AkLicgIiuim5woNqirr7EztDOfJri8uDI8LjKzsb/2wBDASIkJDAqMF40NF7GhHCExsbGxsbG
  xsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsb/wgARCAB5AHkDASEA
  AhEBAxEB/8QAGQAAAwEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAECBAMF/8QAGAEAAwEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEC
  AwT/2gAMAwEAAhADEAAAAfQAXAM9O7YlzoXdLQ5QAIMSL6gA0DS50G6UyRYUyi2NBQhoHMMNzzM2
  VX0BgwKQqSHJDWvTk/McagAMC0TcBUoA9LM8x49ACBjNJlawIlgl0kh8/SIAAekwbYgJiSEUc3WA
  AIdRBrgAhggLOfsAGxVc5xFc6WiBgN08O0AdKbqM551lKuBUjpV1OXWNN0oqohQ84V5pUr3aac8u
  fQ3FOpmnMKXEzWSVLX322WVXD59aamnMEkTNZzehre+ogzLn0p5lEyJzMvN6emmXQAuSIrlunmKX
  E9OhdHswAAAJzQ+tcbnnqtFdSAAD/8QAIBAAAgICAwADAQAAAAAAAAAAAQIAEQMwEBIgIjFAIf/a
  AAgBAQABBQLlsoE+TQIJ1EoTqIUE+SxcoPt3LQLWhluJkKnxkfsR/NRFzG/U8ZWoLsaYXsRj2fah
  6vcG4zv+ipX4CPwH30jCm2qLapkW92NaHDLWxFvyVrUFv2U0BdJ+oODwPrz/AP/EABwRAQACAgMB
  AAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAEAIgETAxIf/aAAgBAwEBPwGvN/Nzox87Hod2O+T8nO+Ud2NkPKYxvHyYNNMa
  Ji8OjGB9sbYwNOegp0//xAAfEQABBAMAAwEAAAAAAAAAAAABAAIRIBAwMQMSIUH/2gAIAQIBAT8B
  pKI0BOEaD9Gk0CGX9oEMkTRugOheylTUoFTcUPajAT9DhIsz7l4irRAyRKc0jLGfpq/mPH2n/8QA
  HhAAAQQBBQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEQEgITAQAAJAUHD/2gAIAQEABj8CzFEvCVDc0JYFyPADceljUvni
  /wD/xAAdEAADAAIDAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAREQMSAhQTBh/9oACAEBAAE/Ic9R2Y3vcR6iHh+A2+Hi
  6LrdR1PR8m0lWNfEVtvFLilwnTpnggTTVXBnhCpClKUpSlKKUd4+evbYkRSlKUpSlKUSq+nRvaxY
  ZSlKUpSlKUpSC/GTlSlKUpSlLi5VypRvnOcKn0QhBInWCEJyhMQglhBomJiFFREIQgkLDGhomZiJ
  JI2sQSIImGhog0Qh3DbzbVrMEuDRCYrr1waqjHa6FzYxz96EoouXp0O1oLgzt6R69vlPZrl7zv/a
  AAwDAQACAAMAAAAQCZ9GgAVrOID+MKOo0R0OMKN+ec1rZcb1FaGkEgox777+BDUwvvfOejgbCEVt
  p82ChkNz+AVXCzANstqAAEMAAP/EABoRAAMBAQEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABERAgITH/2gAIAQMBAT8Q
  Eq4eeENso1wlHa1j9Jj4SVrGXUokiEHh4iExjansPgb0pS8SwvLPQkZSixjwvurR6g+C8UeEHh8S
  RTAYx7W1ZDHhCS1OMVDGJc/XT//EABsRAQEBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAEAERAhMSBh/9oACAECAQE/
  EOHlsItTT9kstHnGIiODw4/eERZEMU6PAs4PrpyO+S3mz1vlttvdiWwXtvNtlzINvNlllDDDt5my
  ywyhvmGOyy2wwwwYcBZbYYYa7u/ktsMfjCGMz7w98s/0D9/J/8QAIxABAAICAgICAgMAAAAAAAAA
  AQARECExQSBRMGGhsXGBkf/aAAgBAQABPxDCgWxl/q4naJ0QW2rDhCfVnIGK21QfaF0xz/bgiWeL
  pKCIXTuzfbRYZLyX7mygIbujDSWOVotlzdeX3KUc/EAKA8y1W3DBssxuGW2eX4AL4dpnCbP68Khw
  NHixgcD4sUjkpn3zhfcvwBJDDgcV4K6rkl/UVS5cuXLhDpgtwMuEduFeFSmWl1yKOZUqVKm5WKlS
  sCCbXiB6Sh4jLgrwrJULQ6E6IFFZVisKw/mjdRdmQgjsglQalmFiokfqrtn1zQkAvwAwiomBwGGk
  1BgSymPWb/iBAhgBKlYGGEiCWv5gUUZJgsY7e36ylagQIEqJEggqXoV+8IgoPFBKYS229RtpD7jH
  hIYYg5SFtM/cMbbeoFFHwc04MnGHKcXl/9k=" clip-path="url(#circ)" />
  <g transform="translate(60.5,60.5)">
    <path d="M0 0A56 56 0 0 0 0 56 56 56 0 0 0 32.916 45.305 56 56 0 0 1 0 0 56
        56 0 0 0 53.259 17.305 56 56 0 0 0 53.259-17.305 56 56 0 0 1 0 0 56 56
        0 0 0 32.916-45.305 56 56 0 0 0 0-56 56 56 0 0 1 0 0 56 56 0 0 0
        -32.916-45.305 56 56 0 0 0-53.259-17.305 56 56 0 0 1 0 0 56 56 0 0 0
        -53.259 17.305 56 56 0 0 0-32.916 45.305 56 56 0 0 1 0 0Z"
        stroke="none" fill="#000" opacity="0.25" transform="rotate(0)">
      <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0"
          to="72" begin="0s" dur="0.6s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </path>
    <circle r="59" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2" fill="none" opacity="0.25" />
    <circle r="55" fill="url(#shine)" stroke="none" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [Circle loading animation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31251181/7394871) от участника  [@r3mainer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1679849/r3mainer).</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Вот  **решение CSS**, в котором я рассмотрю использование только одного элемента.

Я буду использовать форму, которую  создал в этом [предыдущем ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55159993/8620333), а выше я рассмотрю конический градиент [conic-gradient()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/conic-gradient)

На самом деле `conic-Gradient()` поддерживается только в Chrome и Safari, но у нас скоро будет лучшая поддержка:

```css
  .box {
  --R:50px; /*Radius*/
  --c1:grey; /*first color*/
  --c2:#fff; /*second color*/
  
  --g1:var(--c1) 98%, transparent 100%;
  --g2:var(--c2) 98%, transparent 100%;
  width:calc(2*var(--R));
  height:calc(2*var(--R));
  border-radius:100%;
  border:1px solid;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  display:inline-block;
  background:conic-gradient(rgba(128, 0, 128,0.7), rgba(0, 0, 255,0.7),rgba(0, 128, 0,0.7),rgba(255, 255, 0,0.7), rgba(255, 0, 0,0.7), rgba(128, 0, 128,0.7));
  box-shadow:0 3px 5px inset rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.box::before,
.box::after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  width:50%;
  background:
     /*we rotate by 30deg so will use :
       sin(30deg)*R = 0.5xR   
       cos(30deg)*R = 0.866xR 
     */
    radial-gradient(circle var(--R) at calc(var(--R) + 0.866*var(--R)) calc(var(--R) - 0.5*var(--R))  ,var(--g1)),
    radial-gradient(circle var(--R) at calc(var(--R) + 0.5*var(--R))   calc(var(--R) - 0.866*var(--R)),var(--g2)),
    radial-gradient(circle var(--R) at var(--R)                        0                              ,var(--g1)),
    radial-gradient(circle var(--R) at calc(var(--R) - 0.5*var(--R))   calc(var(--R) - 0.866*var(--R)),var(--g2)),
    radial-gradient(circle var(--R) at calc(var(--R) - 0.866*var(--R)) calc(var(--R) - 0.5*var(--R))  ,var(--g1)),
    radial-gradient(circle var(--R) at 0                               var(--R)                        ,var(--g2)),
    radial-gradient(circle var(--R) at calc(var(--R) - 0.866*var(--R)) calc(var(--R) + 0.5*var(--R))  ,var(--g1));   
    transform-origin:right;
    animation:animate 3s linear infinite;
}

/*the same shape rotated*/
.box::after {
   animation-delay:-1.5s;
}

@keyframes animate {
  to {
    transform:rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Вывод:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вращение в противоположном направлении:

```css
.box {
  --R:50px; /*Radius*/
  --c1:grey; /*first color*/
  --c2:#fff; /*second color*/
  
  --g1:var(--c1) 98%, transparent 100%;
  --g2:var(--c2) 98%, transparent 100%;
  width:calc(2*var(--R));
  height:calc(2*var(--R));
  border-radius:100%;
  border:1px solid;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  display:inline-block;
  background:conic-gradient(rgba(128, 0, 128,0.7), rgba(0, 0, 255,0.7),rgba(0, 128, 0,0.7),rgba(255, 255, 0,0.7), rgba(255, 0, 0,0.7), rgba(128, 0, 128,0.7));
  box-shadow:0 3px 5px inset rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.box::before,
.box::after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  width:50%;
  background:
     /*we rotate by 30deg so will use :
       sin(30deg)*R = 0.5xR   
       cos(30deg)*R = 0.866xR 
     */
    radial-gradient(circle var(--R) at calc(var(--R) + 0.866*var(--R)) calc(var(--R) - 0.5*var(--R))  ,var(--g1)),
    radial-gradient(circle var(--R) at calc(var(--R) + 0.5*var(--R))   calc(var(--R) - 0.866*var(--R)),var(--g2)),
    radial-gradient(circle var(--R) at var(--R)                        0                              ,var(--g1)),
    radial-gradient(circle var(--R) at calc(var(--R) - 0.5*var(--R))   calc(var(--R) - 0.866*var(--R)),var(--g2)),
    radial-gradient(circle var(--R) at calc(var(--R) - 0.866*var(--R)) calc(var(--R) - 0.5*var(--R))  ,var(--g1)),
    radial-gradient(circle var(--R) at 0                               var(--R)                        ,var(--g2)),
    radial-gradient(circle var(--R) at calc(var(--R) - 0.866*var(--R)) calc(var(--R) + 0.5*var(--R))  ,var(--g1));   
    transform-origin:right;
    animation:animate 3s linear infinite;
}

/*the same shape rotated*/
.box::after {
   animation-delay:-1.5s;
}

@keyframes animate {
  from {
    transform:scale(-1,1) rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform:scale(-1,1) rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [Circle loading animation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56473673/7394871)
 от участника  [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>